# How to sum the actual value with the above row value only for a specific key on a mySQL Select

Tags: mysql, sql

using a example from here I just come up with part of a solution. Now I can sum the values with the value of the above row, but in this case I just need to sum values for the same `SE_NOME` column.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d93/1) is a example on sqlfiddle:

It's a balance, not a total as below.

```
| SE_NOME | PNT |BALANCE|
|---------|-----|-------|
|     ARP | 100 |   100 |
|     ARP | 500 |   600 |
|     DEE | 200 |   200 |
|     DEE | 200 |   400 |
|     DEE | 200 |   800 |
|     DFF | 300 |   300 |
|     HGG | 400 |   400 |
|     HGG | 400 |   800 |
|     HGG | 400 |  1200 |
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit, what would be your expected output ?

Comment: Mr. rtruszk just come with a excellent answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
select
    PreAgg.SE_NOME,
    PreAgg.PNT,
    CASE 
        WHEN @PrevNome<>PreAgg.SE_NOME THEN @PrevBal := PreAgg.PNT 
        ELSE @PrevBal := @PrevBal + PreAgg.PNT 
    END as Total,
    @PrevNome := PreAgg.SE_NOME as Nome
from 
  ( select
          eg.SE_NOME,
          eg.PNT
       from
          energia as eg
       order by
          eg.SE_NOME ) as PreAgg,
  ( select @PrevBal := 0.00 ) as SqlVars1,
  ( select @PrevNome := '' ) as SqlVars2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking how to sum up rows with same SE_NOME values.Then you can do some thing like this:

```
SELECT SUM(PNT) AS TOTAL FROM energia where SE_NOME = 'DEE'
```

or any value of SE_NOME that you want to use.

Comment: I need exactly as point on the fiddle, it is a balance (the actual value plus the previous). As explained on the edited question.